# How to make newly selected html option the first choice on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

being new to javascript this seems like a totally solvable/easy problem but I’m struggling in finding a solution.

How can I make it so that after a user has selected an option from a dropdown list and then ‘save’ their option (the page they were on has been redirected) and then they go back to that dropdown list and have the option they selected be the top option?

As of now, the list is sorted with the ‘default’ option selected first and the rest in alphabetical order. Then if a user selects another option, the list is sorted so that is the top option and the rest is alphabetical order. How do I keep that order on refresh of the page?

js

```
// Below function: This sorts the html dropdown list so that the top option is the selected option. 

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function(){

                $(this).html($('option', this).sort(function(a,b){

                    if(a.text == b.text) {

                        return 0;

                    }

                    if(a.text > b.text) {

                        return 1;

                    } else {

                        return -1;

                    }

                }));

                var nSel = $('option:selected', this).detach();

                $(this).prepend(nSel);

                // $('select').prepend(nSel);

                $("select").val(nSel);

                myDropdown.value = myTextBox.value;

            });

        });

    })
```

html/twig

```
 <div class = "dropdowns">

    <select id = "dropdown">

          <option> name </option>

          {% for key, value in Infos|sort %}

                 <option value="{{ key }} | {{ value }}"> {{ key }} | {{ value }} </option>

          {% endfor %}        

    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use cookies if its only client-side JavaScript.

See here:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

To summarize:  You'll have to set the cookie string.

```
document.cookie = "selectedOption=" + option;
```

And then manually split the string and parse the keys/values.